# Need to automate the Start_date and End_date in Python from Oracle database

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, date, datetime

I'm new to Python and I'm interested to switch to Python all my current reporting's. As my reports include date frames, mostly of my reports include in the SQL query a "Start_Date" and an "End_Date". I have been looking around on how to write some line of code to do the same in python. Has anyone experienced the same, please help and share. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cx_Oracle
import warnings
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime as dtt

connstr = 'UN/PW@dbpath/DB'  # this is hidden due to security
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
today=date.today()
start_date = input("Enter start_date in MM/DD/YYYY format :")
month, year, day = map(int, start_date.split('/'))
end_date= input("Enter end_date in MM/DD/YYYY format :")
month, year, day = map(int, end_date.split('/'))

# a pop up will require to enter the start_date and the end_date manually
print (start_date)
print (end_date)
05/01/2021
05/31/2021

df=pd.read_sql_query("""select pr_no
, pr_task_no
, to_date(to_char(act_complete_date_time,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'mm/dd/yyyy') as act_complete_date_time

from pr_task
where pr_task_no = 100
and act_complete_date_time between to_date({start_date},'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date({end_date},'mm/dd/yyyy') 
""", conn)

The error that I'm getting is: DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql
': ORA-00936: missing expression
```

So Oracle is not recognizing the date entered and is not running the script.
I have give multiple attempts to format the date so it can be recognized from the database.
Can someone help to achieve this step?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are missing a "f" before the query string, as is

```
df=pd.read_sql_query(f"""select pr_no
, pr_task_no
, to_date(to_char(act_complete_date_time,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'mm/dd/yyyy') as act_complete_date_time

from pr_task
where pr_task_no = 100
and act_complete_date_time between to_date({start_date},'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date({end_date},'mm/dd/yyyy') 
""", conn)
```

without it you are sending the literal {start_date} to the db as the query and it is not replaced with the variable with the same name

as a side note,  this code is considered vulnrable if you are letting an unknown user set the times, he or she could use sql injection to edit you query (imagine if instead of a date they put ;drop table pr_task)

Comment: Thank you DorElias, it worked. In addition I had placed the  start date and end_date in single quotes as follows:
to_date('{start_date}','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('{end_date}','mm/dd/yyyy')

Also that table and all the query is a made up, I'm also careful to share original content.
Thank you so much!

Comment: You have a security risk and potential performance problem because you are using f-strings instead of bind variables.